# Float Curve node : is there something similar that can be used for anticipation / bounce?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I like to use the Float Curve node in Geometry Nodes, it allows me to tweak how data evolves (let's say from 0 to 1) and break how linear they are.

[image]

But I'm searching for something a bit different.  I would like to make a transition that would have some anticipation then a bounce.
Instead of the "diagonal" default curve of the *Float Curve* node, I would then need a node that works the same (progression from 0 to 1), but with an horizontal line instead of the "diagonal" line of the Float Curve node.

Then I could tweak it to have some anticipation and "elasticity" to my transition:

[image]

The difference is that I can go lower than 0 and higher than 1, if you see what I mean.

Is there something like this existing, or how do you handle this ?

Thanks !

Comment: no, there is no node for that. Either you use math nodes for that or you adapt the float curve that it looks like you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, but do you know you can change the limits of the float curve by going into the dropdown in the top right of the node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclip the float curve.

1. Disable the Clipping.
2. Click on the "*-*" Magnifying Glass.

[image: float curve node unclip]